# Server control of browser cache expiration timeout

Tags: caching, iis, browser

We have an online learning management system hosted in IIS.  A common problem is learners have to clear browser cache to resume an online course that had minor updates in recent history.

The LMS is classic ASP, the server is Windows 2012, IIS 7.

What I am hoping is that IIS has a setting to serve files with a timeout on the cache expiration that the client browser will honor.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "httpExpires" attribute which specifies a date and time that the content should expire, You need to add an HTTP "Expires" header to the response.

To configure a cache expiration date for a Web site or application you could follow the below steps:

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- In the Connections    pane, go to the site for which you want to
  disable caching.
- From the feature view, select HTTP Response Headers.

[image]

- In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the
  Actions pane.
- In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, check the box to
  expire Web content, select the option to expire after a specific
  interval or at a specific time, and then click OK.

[image]

You could also refer below article for more detail information:
[Client Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache)

Regards,
Jalpa